# Stay active while sleeping in Python

Tags: python, sleep

```
if ":!giveaway" in prevdata and senderusr in securelist and agive == 0:
    agive = agive+1
    message("Giveaway started by: " + senderusr)
    time.sleep(3)
    agive = 0
    enteredgiveaway = enteredgiveaway.rstrip()
    enteredgiveaway = enteredgiveaway.split(" ")
    gg = random.choice(enteredgiveaway)
    message("The winner of the giveaway is: " + gg)
    gg = ""
    enteredgiveaway = ""

if "PRIVMSG" in prevdata and agive == 1:
    enteredgiveaway += senderusr + " "
```

The first `if` starts a giveaway and then after 3 seconds will select a random user that typed in the IRC and message the IRC saying whoever won.

However, my problem is that the second `if` is unable to collect users because the first command sleeps the program and the other `if` is unable to work.

**How do I sleep but have the program be able to do to other stuff ?**

(IRC Bot)

Entire Code : http://pastebin.com/Qr8hAH14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the first if clause set a [`Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects), calling a method that does what you now do after sleeping.

```
from threading import Timer

def giveaway():
    agive = 0
    enteredgiveaway = enteredgiveaway.rstrip()
    enteredgiveaway = enteredgiveaway.split(" ")
    gg = random.choice(enteredgiveaway)
    message("The winner of the giveaway is: " + gg)
    gg = ""
    enteredgiveaway = ""
```

and in your quoted code segment:

```
if ":!giveaway" in prevdata and senderusr in securelist and agive == 0:
    agive = agive+1
    message("Giveaway started by: " + senderusr)
    t = Timer(3, giveaway)
    t.start()

...
```

This is a bit sketchy, as I can't tell where, for example, `enteredgiveaway` is coming from in your code sample. So, depending on the rest of your code, you might have to reorganize/restructure a bit to make it work. It's probably better too to put everything in a class and use instance variables, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: I think this is basically what i'm wanting. However i need to edit it to work with my code. Will reply again if i get it working with this.

Comment: Updated main post with my entire code.

Using your code i get:
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 755, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "Updating.py", line 156, in giveaway
    enteredgiveaway = enteredgiveaway.rstrip()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enteredgiveaway' referenced before assignment

Not sure why? Can functions not access the global variables?

Comment: They can, but only if you tell them to. The simplest (not the cleanest..) fix would be to add `global enteredgiveaway` at the start of `giveaway()`